# How do i make it so that the List View message clicks and goes to Website. url in message?

Tags: android, beacon, google-nearby

Using the hello-beacon code lab to make a app that retrieves attachment
messages from the google dashboard from my beacon..the app works fine and the messages appear in a list view on the app..My question is how do i make the messages contain a message with a URL link like google nearby once did..then allow the user to click on the message and go to that messages website...I understand the click part and the app receives the messages...what is missing..thanks for any help!

```
package com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.samples.hellobeacons;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.Nearby;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.Messages;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.MessageListener;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.MessagesOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.NearbyMessagesStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.NearbyPermissions;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.Strategy;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.SubscribeOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 1111;

    private static final String KEY_SUBSCRIBED = "subscribed";

    /**
     * The entry point to Google Play Services.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /**
     * The container {@link android.view.ViewGroup} for the minimal UI associated with this sample.
     */
    private RelativeLayout mContainer;

    /**
     * Tracks subscription state. Set to true when a call to
     * {@link Messages#subscribe(GoogleApiClient, MessageListener)} succeeds.
     */
    private boolean mSubscribed = false;

    /**
     * Adapter for working with messages from nearby beacons.
     */
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mNearbyMessagesArrayAdapter;

    /**
     * Backing data structure for {@code mNearbyMessagesArrayAdapter}.
     */
    private List<String> mNearbyMessagesList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mSubscribed = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_SUBSCRIBED, false);
        }

        mContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_container);

        if (!havePermissions()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Requesting permissions needed for this app.");
            requestPermissions();
        }

        final List<String> cachedMessages = Utils.getCachedMessages(this);
        if (cachedMessages != null) {
            mNearbyMessagesList.addAll(cachedMessages);
        }

        final ListView nearbyMessagesListView = (ListView) findViewById(
                R.id.nearby_messages_list_view);
        mNearbyMessagesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mNearbyMessagesList);
        if (nearbyMessagesListView != null) {
            nearbyMessagesListView.setAdapter(mNearbyMessagesArrayAdapter);
        }



        /**
         * this area i think is wear i put the click listener...but how do i get
         * the URL from out of the message...I want the messages to contain a URL
         * then when the client clicks the message it goes to that  website!
         * just like google nearby notifications did!
         */

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        getSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        if (havePermissions()) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode != PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
            String permission = permissions[i];
            if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Permission denied without 'NEVER ASK AGAIN': " + permission);
                    showRequestPermissionsSnackbar();
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Permission denied with 'NEVER ASK AGAIN': " + permission);
                    showLinkToSettingsSnackbar();
                }
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Permission granted, building GoogleApiClient");
                buildGoogleApiClient();
            }
        }
    }

    private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Nearby.MESSAGES_API, new MessagesOptions.Builder()
                        .setPermissions(NearbyPermissions.BLE).build())
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                    .build();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        getSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (mContainer != null) {
            Snackbar.make(mContainer, "Exception while connecting to Google Play services: " +
                            connectionResult.getErrorMessage(),
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Connection suspended. Error code: " + i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connected");
        subscribe();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if (TextUtils.equals(key, Utils.KEY_CACHED_MESSAGES)) {
            mNearbyMessagesList.clear();
            mNearbyMessagesList.addAll(Utils.getCachedMessages(this));
            mNearbyMessagesArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(KEY_SUBSCRIBED, mSubscribed);
    }

    private boolean havePermissions() {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private void requestPermissions() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /**
     * Calls {@link Messages#subscribe(GoogleApiClient, MessageListener, SubscribeOptions)},
     * using a {@link Strategy} for BLE scanning. Attaches a {@link ResultCallback} to monitor
     * whether the call to {@code subscribe()} succeeded or failed.
     */
    private void subscribe() {
        // In this sample, we subscribe when the activity is launched, but not on device orientation
        // change.
        if (mSubscribed) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Already subscribed.");
            return;
        }

        SubscribeOptions options = new SubscribeOptions.Builder()
                .setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY)
                .build();

        Nearby.Messages.subscribe(mGoogleApiClient, getPendingIntent(), options)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                        if (status.isSuccess()) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Subscribed successfully.");
                            startService(getBackgroundSubscribeServiceIntent());
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Operation failed. Error: " +
                                    NearbyMessagesStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(
                                            status.getStatusCode()));
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private PendingIntent getPendingIntent() {
        return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                getBackgroundSubscribeServiceIntent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    private Intent getBackgroundSubscribeServiceIntent() {
        return new Intent(this, BackgroundSubscribeIntentService.class);
    }

    /**
     * Displays {@link Snackbar} instructing user to visit Settings to grant permissions required by
     * this application.
     */
    private void showLinkToSettingsSnackbar() {
        if (mContainer == null) {
            return;
        }
        Snackbar.make(mContainer,
                R.string.permission_denied_explanation,
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction(R.string.settings, new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // Build intent that displays the App settings screen.
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",
                                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null);
                        intent.setData(uri);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }).show();
    }

    /**
     * Displays {@link Snackbar} with button for the user to re-initiate the permission workflow.
     */
    private void showRequestPermissionsSnackbar() {
        if (mContainer == null) {
            return;
        }
        Snackbar.make(mContainer, R.string.permission_rationale,
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction(R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // Request permission.
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                }).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this after initializing your listview :

```
nearbyMessagesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
        long arg3) 
  {
        String listitem = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position); 
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
        Uri.parse(listitem ));
        startActivity(browserIntent);   
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank You So much..it works great!!!!!! The attachment (URL) gets read by the app, and the message appears in the list View...when i click on it it goes to the website, the only problem I have now is I can only add the web link...how would i go about parsing it so that i could have a small message appear before the web link..that message I put into my google beacon dashboard under attachments?

Comment: I ended up using this and it worked to extract url from message..thanks again!          String listitem = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                    String wordtofind =(listitem.substring(listitem.lastIndexOf("-")+ 2));